# R foreach %dopar% not working with 6+ inputs

Tags: r, foreach

I'm new to parallel processing and am encountering an issue. I'm downloading data using openalexR online and, due to the large amount of data, I'm trying to parallelize the process by downloading data for each month separately.

The following code works fine in serial (`%do%` instead of `%dopar%`) and in parallel if I only provide it with five or fewer months to process (e.g., it works with `months_succA` and `months_succB`). It fails in parallel with six or more inputs (e.g., with `months_fail`), and returns one of the errors `\<simpleError: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors\>` or `<simpleError in data[[i]]: subscript out of bounds>`. The line that seems to fail is "`oa2df`" but I can't figure out where in this function. (See documentation [here](https://github.com/ropensci/openalexR/blob/main/R/oa2df.R).)

Note that the issue does not seem to be a specific month, as each runs fine in smaller chunks. I am getting the same error on my local laptop, a virtual server, or on my university's high-performance computing cluster, and I get the same issue no matter how many cores I use.

Any ideas? My hunch is that there's an issue when a core is "assigned" a second parameter, but I really don't know.

```
# Setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------

library(openalexR)
library(tidyverse)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

# Number of cores to use for parallel tasks 
parallel = 1
if (parallel==1) {
  cores = 6 #detectCores() - 1
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(cores)
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
  print(cores)
}

# DOWNLOAD DATA ---------------------------------------------------------------

months_fail = seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("1990-07-01")-1, "months")
months_succA = seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("1990-04-01")-1, "months")
months_succB = seq(as.Date("1990-03-01"), as.Date("1990-07-01")-1, "months")

foreach(mon = list(months_fail, months_succA, months_succB)[[3]],
        .errorhandling = "pass",
        .packages = c("openalexR", "tidyverse", "foreach")) %dopar% {
          
          # core query for given year
          query_core <- 
            oa_query(
              entity = "works",
              concepts.id = "C144024400", 
              has_references = "true",
              has_abstract = "true",
              authors_count = ">0",
              from_publication_date = mon, #start of month
              to_publication_date = seq(mon, length=2, by="days")[2]-1, #end of month
              options = list(sort = "cited_by_count:desc"),
              verbose = FALSE
            )
          
          # core response to df
          res_core <- 
            query_core %>%
            oa_request(per_page = 200, verbose = TRUE) %>%
            oa2df(entity = "works") 
          
          # ... save res_core output to file (redacted for post)

          # null
          return(NULL)
}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Usually, when APIs stop working once you start asking for more data at a time, it is because the server stops responding to you. Messing around a bit with your script, I can see `HTTP status 429 Too Many Requests` messages (not displayed by `foreach`), suggesting that this may be the issue here. At the very least, you should consider being "polite" and adding your email to your requests: https://docs.openalex.org/how-to-use-the-api/rate-limits-and-authentication

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!! I completely forgot about this being a possible issue. (And yes, thank you! I am in the "polite" pool--I removed it for the sake of the example code.)

If you are able, can you share briefly what you did to figure out there were suppressed `HTTP status 429 Too Many Requests`?

Comment: I put your code into a function and ran with `future` instead of `dopar`.